# org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity:org.many_to_many.model.Course column Course_ID

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, many-to-many

I am doing a simple many to many mapping in hibernate using XML mapping.In this project i get the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: org.many_to_many.model.Course column: Course_ID (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:764)
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:782)
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:804)
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:539)
at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:464)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
at org.many_to_many.client.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:16)
```

Student class:

```
private int student_ID;
private String student_Name;
private Set<Course> courses;
//getter,setter and constructor
```

Course class:

```
private int course_ID;
private String course_Name;
private Set<Student> students;
//getter,setter and constructor
```

student.hbm.xml :

```
<class name = "org.many_to_many.model.Student" table = "STUDENT">
   <id name = "student_ID" column = "Student_ID">
      <generator class = "native"></generator>
   </id>
   <property name = "student_Name" column = "Student_Name"></property>
   <set name = "course" table = "student_course" inverse = "true">
     <key column = "Student_ID"/>
     <many-to-many column = "Course_ID" class =     "org.many_to_many.model.Course"/>
   </set>
</class>
```

course.hbm.xml :

```
 <class name = "org.many_to_many.model.Course" table = "COURSE">
   <id name = "course_ID" column = "Course_ID">
      <generator class = "native"></generator>
   </id>
   <property name = "course_Name" column = "Course_ID"></property>
   <set name = "students" table = "student_course" cascade = "all" inverse = "true">
     <key column = "Course_ID"/>
     <many-to-many class = "org.many_to_many.model.Student" column = "Student_ID"></many-to-many>
   </set>
</class>
```

could anyone tell me what is my mistake or could solve this problem with some explanation on many to many mapping. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In course.hbm.xml you have `<property name = "course_Name" column = "Course_ID"></property>`

Comment: oh i got it.Thank u very much